# ADFS EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage property is missing

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, service-provider, idp

I am working on SAML authentication for my application using ADFS as IDP and IIS server as SP. ADFs has been setup on Windows 2012 R2.
The problem is " I can't access the ADFS Single Sing On page". this is the error that i am getting on adfs
Error - Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/ls/ to process the incoming request.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

I have googled the solution and find out that i have to enable the "EnableIdpInitiatedSignonPage" that is one of the ADFS property - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-initiatedsignon

According to the docs "Get-AdfsProperties" command has to show the "EnableIdpInitiatedSignonPage" property. but i am not getting it when i run "Get-AdfsProperties".

is there any way to add this property or any other solution.

Thanks

Comment: If you are on a legacy version of Windows and legacy ADFS, this property is not there. For if you view the MS provided documentation as you provided in your post, you see this is for WS216 and higher...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am facing the same issue...